# Why is Amen exclusive to the Chazzan during Tefillah?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, chazzan-prayer-leader, amen

Normally, if I hear my good friend Shimon say a bracha, I answer Amen. Nonetheless, if it's during davening, and I hear him finish a bracha, it appears to be common practice to not say Amen.

In other words, (as far as I observed) during davening everyone exclusively says Amen to the brachos of the Chazzan, and to no one else's.

But why is this so? Shouldn't Amen normally be said on *all* brachos?

Comment: +1. Re "(as far a I observed) during davening everyone exclusively says Amen to the brachos of Chazzan, and to no one else": and to _kohanim_, no?

Comment: Whose berachos would you expect to say amen to during davening? Most people daven almost silently. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @msh210 yes, kohanim too, but none of the "regular" congregants.

Comment: @curiouser that might be true, but lots of people daven aloud.

Comment: I wonder if you're supposed to be concentrating so deeply that you shouldn't notice someone else's bracha, so even if you do you don't respond.

Comment: @Curiouser, I frequently say have opportunity to (and do) respond "_amen_" when people near me finish _birchos k'rias sh'ma_.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, well, when you're in the middle of a _t'fila_ you generally don't respond anyway (though it depends what you're responding to and what you're in the middle of). Between paragraphs, as in my comment just above, what should I be concentrating on?

Comment: I think it's a mistake.  I answer to others who I hear.

Comment: @Curiouser Many people Daven audibly (if not loudly), and there are always some individuals who like to sing the end of the Berachah they are saying (especially at Ma'ariv for Shabbath/Yom Tov), and that generally includes the closing Baruch. I enjoy singing it myself, but to avoid creating a problem for those around me I typically cut off and recite Baruch inaudibly.

Comment: @msh210, between paragraphs I assume you're supposed to concentrate either on what you've just said or what you're preparing to say.  I'm just speculating, though, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree with msh210 and YDK. I often say amen to other peoples birkot kriat shema while waiting for the chazzan to finish.

Comment: maybe the idea of showing unity among the tzibur and not everyone doing something different? In a different situation such as for an individual's bracha there is only that individual's bracha you are saying amen to at one time. Also it if we are to respond to every bracha being said in the room we might end up seriously compromising our own davening in order to respond to to others.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18805/what-can-be-done-to-hush-someone-praying-a-loud-amidah?noredirect=1#comment214656_18805

Answer (score 3):

See [OC 6 (4) and MB](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=23) who records a custom that each congregant says the morning blessings and the others answer omain (without the intention to fulfill their obligation by saying omain). See MB s.k. 13, who mentions a supporting view and the view of the Pri Megodim that only the Chazzan should say these blessings aloud. MB says that each place should follow its custom. See also s.k. 14.

IMHO, there ought to be no objection to answering omain to other blessings (like putting on tefillin).

Comment: Pri Megadim sounds circumstancial.

Answer (score 0):

The rambam specifically forbids saying amen to birkot kriyat shema and shmoneh esrei if it is not from the chazan in a minyan. Other rishonim states that one can say amen to those of kriyat shema, but saying amen to shmoneh esrei of someone who’s whispering too loudly is specifically forbidden.

Comment: Where does Rambam say that? Please [edit] to clarify