# Talking during the Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

If 2 or more people are talking during the congregation's silent Shemoneh Esrei, are you allowed to and in what way may you silence them?

Can you hush or snap at them? Can you interrupt your own Shemoneh Esrei to talk to them? In which case, should you whisper or shout at them?

Please cite all sources. Thank you!

Comment: In the mishna berurah (dont know exactly where), it says "גוערין בו" regarding someone who talks during davening (any part) that means to yell at them. The question is, does that mean during davening? In which case you will only disturb more people. Or maybe after davening, or ask him to come outside and then yell at him...

Comment: What's special about the amount "2 or more"? Why not even one (for whatever may or may not be allowed)?

Comment: I doubt that you should interrupt your own Amidah to tell others to keep quiet. How much more so that you're forbidden to stop your Amidah to talk to them and join in their conversation! I don't get it. What would make you think that if others are doing something forbidden that you should join them? have I mistranslated your question, here?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18805/759

Comment: @Salmononius2 Probably just practicality. Usually you need someone to talk to.